# Kubernetes - dynamic namespaces / security

Tags: security, dynamic, kubernetes, namespaces

user1 and user2 have been assigned "admin" role in K8s cluster where they can only work within the namepsace they are assigned. In the case below, ns1 and ns2 respectively

user1 --> assigned namespace ns1

user2 --> assigned namespace ns2

user3 -->  assigned namespace ns3 and also have namespace-admin role assigned.
namespace-admin role (user3) should be able to create any resource in namespace ns3 and any new namespaces he creates in the cluster. This role should have ability to dynamically create new namespaces. But user3 should NOT  have access to ns1 or ns2 namespaces which is not created by user "user3".

user3 will be dynamically creating new namespaces and deploying workloads in those namespaces.

Can this be addressed ? This is similar to Openshift "Projects" concept.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can restrict user3 to create/delete resources only in the namespace ns3 using a `Role` bind that role to user3.

Then you can use `ClusterRole` with only access to the `namespaces` resource and allow it to `create, delete, etc`

Something like this:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: user-namespace-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services", "endpoints", "pods"] # etc...
  verbs: ["get", "list", "create"] # etc
```

Then:

```
kubectl create rolebinding user-namespace-binding --role=user-namespace-role --user=user3 --namespace=my-namespace
```

Then:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cluster-role-all-namespaces
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespaces"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"] # etc
```

Then:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding all-namespaces-binding --clusterrole=cluster-role-all-namespaces --user=user3
```

For user1 and user2 you can create a `Role` and `RoleBinding` for their unique namespaces.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try. But, the verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"] # etc wil give permission to user3 to see other namespaces also right ?    Ex: user3 can see namespace ns1 and ns2 created and dedicated for user 1 and user2 respectively

Comment: Yep, should be able to.  # etc is a comment btw

Answer (score 0):

> user3 should be able to create any resource in namespace ns3 and any new namespaces he creates in the cluster.

To achieve dynamic permissions, you'd need a component granting user 3 permissions in the namespaces they create (which is what the openshift projects API handler does)

Comment: Yup exactly. I am looking a model to implement the concepts of Openshift " projects" in vanila kubernetes. Any thought on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the post is 4 years old, but if someone stumbles on this thread, ["Hierarchical Namespaces"](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/08/14/introducing-hierarchical-namespaces/) is something that could work in this scenario. In this case you assign user3 the needed permissions to ns3 and user3 can then create "subnamespaces" from ns3, where all of the objects (the RoleBinding, etc.) will be inherited.